# scala JavaTokenParsers Parser[Any] from String

Tags: scala

I am newbie in scala 
Сan someone explain how string "2222222222" will be cast to Parser[Any] in example bellow? why Parser[Any] is acceptable from Sting?

```
object TestParser extends JavaTokenParsers
{
  def a : Parser[Any] = "2222222222"
}
```

what method of Parser[+T] class I need to explore for understand it? 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's resolved by **implicit conversions**

```
implicit def literal(s: String): Parser[String]
```

in RegexParsers